# wordpress costum search query to search in costum post types by posta meta values

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a travel theme in which I have created some custom posts like Cities, Locations, Destinations and Hotels and to add further information to those custom posts I have created few meta boxes with some meta keys like Address, rent, rooms for hotel and How to reach for cities, Destination, and Location now I am having a search form on the index page to search for hotel based on the custom meta keys for hotel custom posts for which I have to create my own custom search function in function.php and by seeing the wordpress tutorials to create [custom search form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form) I can only have single GET variable "?s=" which display the result in search.php only if it contain some string so is it possible to customise search form in such a way that wee can pass more then one search variable and still can display result on search.php template.I have search every ware and tried different plugins but the only functionality most of them provide to extend the search area of search query which by default searches only in post content and post title and changing it to search in the tags, category and custom post type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is explained here: [Enhancing WordPress Custom Fields with Search Filtering](http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/custom-fields-search/)

Comment: Thanks coopersita for your help but in above tutorial the developer is is saving a custom meta field and displaying the related post according to it but what my question is can wee create a search function in our theme that renders the search.php to show the result based on the GET variable passed by the custom search form not like default search form which sends the GET variable in a string storing in a variable 's' or can wee make some edition in default search form to get results based on more then one GET variable .

Comment: Then maybe this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-search-form-in-wordpress-for-custom-post-types/  this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38361/advanced-search-form-with-filters-for-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-fields and this are closer: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-picker/

Comment: thanks for the help all the links given above are extending the search area of the wordpress search form which by default searches only in comments content and title but though the second link gives some information about filters and how to use session in wordpress which is really help full but I solved my problem in my own way by creating a custom form and sending its content throw php GET method which ultimately renders index.php when the Get variable is empty or home.php when GET variable is having some data in it and writing some code in home.php to handle that GET request and display